# Fastest method to create 2D numpy array whose elements are in range

Tags: numpy, range

I want to create a 2D numpy array where I want to store the coordinates of the pixels such that numpy array looks like this

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), ...., (0, 510), (0, 511)
 (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), ...., (1, 510), (1, 511)
 ..
 ..
 ..
 (511, 0), (511, 1), (511, 2), ...., (511, 510), (511, 511)]
```

This is a ridiculous question but I couldn't find anything yet.

Comment: The way you have it formatted, it looks like you want a 3D array of shape (512, 512, 2) ... but the syntactic markup you've given is for a 2D array of shape (512 * 512, 2). Could you clarify ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can use [`np.indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) or [`np.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) for more advanced indexing:

```
>>> data=np.indices((512,512)).swapaxes(0,2).swapaxes(0,1)
>>> data.shape
(512, 512, 2)

>>> data[5,0]
array([5, 0])
>>> data[5,25]
array([ 5, 25])
```

This may look odd because its really made to do something like this:

```
>>> a=np.ones((3,3))
>>> ind=np.indices((2,1))
>>> a[ind[0],ind[1]]=0
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

A `mgrid` example:

```
np.mgrid[0:512,0:512].swapaxes(0,2).swapaxes(0,1)
```

A meshgrid example:

```
>>> a=np.arange(0,512)
>>> x,y=np.meshgrid(a,a)
>>> ind=np.dstack((y,x))
>>> ind.shape
(512, 512, 2)

>>> ind[5,0]
array([5, 0])
```

All are equivalent ways of doing this; however, `meshgrid` can be used to create non-uniform grids.

If you do not mind switching row/column indices you can drop the final `swapaxes(0,1)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.ogrid` here. Instead of storing a `tuple`, store it in a 3D array.

```
>>> t_row, t_col = np.ogrid[0:512, 0:512]
>>> a = np.zeros((512, 512, 2), dtype=np.uint8)
>>> t_row, t_col = np.ogrid[0:512, 0:512]
>>> a[t_row, t_col, 0] = t_row
>>> a[t_row, t_col, 1] = t_col
```

This should do the trick. Hopefully you can use this, instead of the tuple.

Chintak

Answer (score 3):

The example in the question is not completely clear - either extra commas are missing or extra brakets.

This one - example ranges 3, 4 for clarity - provides the solution for the first variant and produces a 2D array in effect (as the question title suggests) - "listing" all coordinates:

```
>>> np.indices((3,4)).reshape(2,-1).T
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 3]])
```

---

The other variant was already shown in another answer by using 2x `.swapaxes()` - but it could also be done with one `np.rollaxis()` (or the new `np.moveaxis()`) :

```
>>> np.rollaxis(np.indices((3,4)), 0, 2+1)
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2],
        [0, 3]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 3]],

       [[2, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [2, 3]]])
>>> _[0,1]
array([0, 1])
```

This method also works the same for N-dimensional indices, e.g.:

```
>>> np.rollaxis(np.indices((5,6,7)), 0, 3+1)
```

Note: The function `np.indices` works indeed (C-speed) fast for big ranges.